# Calling .NET DLL function from flash

Tags: .net, actionscript-3, flash, dll, flash-builder

How to call .NET DLL functions from actionscript. I'm creating a flash application running on a website. I'm not planning to use web service calls because there is a possibility that the service call can be intercepted.

The swf file will be loaded inside a aspx page within a ASP.NET web application. The dll can be loaded as a reference to the same web application.

The idea of calling the DLL file is to authenticate access to the swf file using [Rhino Licensing system](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/rhino-licensing/)

Comment: Where is your dll located and where is the flash located ? Once accessed the swf will be running at cliet side... so if the dll is on server side I see no way how you could call it... ?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve ?   how about using ssl / https  channel ?

Comment: The swf will be loaded inside a asp.net application. The dll can be put as a reference to the asp.net web project

Comment: Cannot use ssl or https. I added some more information

Comment: once again... your flash will run on the client's computer while your asp code will run on the server... you cannot have a link between them.

Answer (score 1):

If an SWF is embeded into an HTML page you can't call DLLs. You will have to wrap these calls into HTTP or Socket requests. If you use AIR (which I think you don't) you would use NativeProcess or a Native Extension.